# C# Sustituir una parte de la cadena por otra de solo espacios

Tags: c#

Tengo un ticket de venta donde tengo permitido 22 caracteres de descripcion de producto pero esta debe de estar alineada a la izquierda y siempre tiene que tener la cadena 22 caracteres con espaciados para poder alinearla con otra columna de precio.

Ejemplo

```
string RowOriginal = "                      ";//<- 22 caracteres
string REjemplo1   = "2xleche               ";//<- 22 caracteres
string REjemplo2   = "5xgalletas            ";//<- 22 caracteres
```

Ticket

```
Descripcion             Importe 
2xleche                  $37
5xgalletas               $45
```

Comment: Y cuál es tu pregunta? Qué has intentado hasta ahora para resolver tu problema? Qué falla? Qué error obtienes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar el método [PadRight](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_PadRight_System_Int32_). Este método te permite añadir espacios a tu string hasta alcanzar la dimensión especificada, que es exáctamente lo que buscas.

```
var str = "leche";
var resultString = str.PadRight(22)
// resultString sería igual a: "leche                 "
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo saber más o menos qué es lo que quieres, espero que esto te sirva para ayudarte en algo. Usa este método.

```
public static string texto22Caracteres(string texto){
    while (texto.Length < 23){
        texto=texto+" ";
    }
    return texto;
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Pues si quieres simular el detalle de un ticket en vez de calcular espacios lo que podrías usar son las tabulaciones qué sería mas práctico:

```
string text = "Name\tTest 1\tTest 2\tTest 3\n";

text = text + "Joe\t95\t88\t91\n";
```

Donde cada `\t` es una columna.

Por otra parte también puedes usar la función `Replace` así sin mas

```
 String str = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";

 str.Replace(' ', ',')

 //1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```